# Does nhibernate work with .net core?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, asp.net-core

I tried to download the package with nuget in .net core 1.0 console application but it failed to build.
Is there any version work with .net core and it is cross platform or not?

Comment: This seems to come with NHibernate 5: [Support for .NET Core 1.0](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3807)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Now available

I revisited this answer and I found nhibernate seems now available for dotnet core: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate/

They released the first version around dec 2017.

## Original Answer

[Nhibernate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate/) seems to only have 1 dependency: [Iesi Collections](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Iesi.Collections/).

Both have no reference to any Netstandard libraries or dlls. which you will basically need to make any library or application.

For example lookt at [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cloudinary.Core/) packages .NETStandard 1.6.

This is a good indication to know if the package was build for dotnet core or not.

`Iesi.collections` nuget package its last update (2013-02) pre-dates dotnet core. So save to say it wasn't tested nor build with dotnet core.

### Alternative ORM's

- [Entity framework Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/) (Does not have all EF features, and they say not production ready, but very stable, and probably your best choice out there)
- [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) (Very small and lightweight)
- [Artisan ORM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Artisan.ORM/) (a new orm)

Search for orm and check the last updated date. This gives you a good indication of what you can use. (last updated in  the last 3-6 months).

Comment: EF Core is still not production ready and even Microsoft doesn't recommend to use it as replacement for EF6, as much of the core features are not yet implemented.

Comment: @Tseng Ofcourse this is true, but this was not a specified constraint in the question. And since he wants a cross-platform version i'd recommend entity framework Core.

Comment: .Net Core 1 is missing too much. Support is expected to be available for .Net Standard 2.0.

Comment: Just commenting to say that Entity Framework Core is a grabasstic pile of amphibian sh**t

Answer (score 9):

I think the best answer is the Jira Item on NHibernate :

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3807

Here you can see the current state.

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate has moved from JIRA to GitHub some time ago.

You can now track the progress in these items:

- GitHub issue: [NH-3807 - Support for .NET Core 2.0](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/954)
- Current pull request: [NH-3807 - Support for .NET Core 2.0](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/633)

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core 1.0 is supported by NHibernate according to that [pull request](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/504) but with .NET Core 2.0 you will have another [major update](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/633) which is still under review.